# MVC Area and Ajax issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have one Area Named Test. Inside this area, I have script folder which contains JS file. I am making one ajax call from this js to the controller in a Root directory. This is not working. Ajax call returns 302 found and call Index method of that controller.

How can I make this working?

Structure of Area
  TeasArea -> Scripts -> test.js

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (Res) {
```

value of `url` is `'/controllername/Methodname'`, where this `controller` resides in Root directory's Controllers folder.

**Note :** I am generating this url using `@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName", new { area = "" });`

Action Method in Controller looks like

```
public JsonResult sampleprint(FormCollection formData)
{
   /// Code goes here.
}
```

Comment: What does the controller action look like? A 302 status code is a successful response. It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Yea please show your controller action.

Comment: public JsonResult sampleprint(FormCollection formData) is signature of method. This method is in a controller in root directory's Controllers folder.

Comment: This method not get called at all. That is the actual issue.

Comment: Do you annotate that method with `[HttpPost]`? I guess it doesn't matter where your .js file is, as long as the url is correct, the method should be involved.

Comment: You have redirection configured for this url. It could be in the web.config; it could be in IIS; it could be the controller returns a redirect response (which you do not show).